# Guava cache listener for insertions

Tags: java, guava

We'd find it very useful to have an `AddListener` to complement `RemovalListener` in Google Guava.

Is there a suitable alternative to an `AddListener` that would complement `RemovalListener`?

Comment: Is SO really the appropriate place for a feature request for Guava?

Comment: I answered the part after "if not.." :)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well, it's all in the phrasing. Maybe all he's really asking is "how do I get this behavior I want", and he did get a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide that yourself - just pass your custom listener to your computing `Function`, and whenever you compute a value, notify the listener.

If you are using `asMap().put(..)`, then you'd have to wrap the whole thing in in your custom classes that delegate to the originals but also invoke the addition listener.