# Guava what methods are being called when insert and delete

Tags: java, guava

I have my own cache like this:

```
LoadingCache<String, MT> g = (LoadingCache<String, MT>) CacheBuilder
                .newBuilder().maximumSize(5)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, MT>() {

                    @Override
                    public MT load(String arg0) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("load for key " + arg0);
                        if (Singlten.getInstance().mts.containsKey(arg0)) {
                            return Singlten.getInstance().mts.get(arg0);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                });
```

i want to know if it is possible (and supported by guava) to that have functions that are being called when data is being inserted and deleted from my cache?

it is like i want to do some tasks when inserting and deleting from cacche

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978169/guava-feature-request-cachebuilder-addlistener

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in that question, I knew how to set a delete (removal) listener. but i couldn't find a listener when something is being added.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis did you get please from that question how to make a listener on adding? i couldn't understand it

Comment: What it's saying is that there is no listener for cache additions. I think what the answer is trying to propose is that you add a wrapper for your use of the `Cache` and add the add listener there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't know how to add that wrapper. i did a work around which is when making a method, that method will do the things that i want the listener to do, and then it inserts to the cache, it is working, but this is just a work around until someone help me here

Comment: Well, what happens when something is added is your `load` method gets called...

Comment: @LouisWasserman no no, that is why someone called the get,

Answer (score 0):

*There are several different options, depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. You may have better luck asking more directly [what you're trying to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573), rather than how to implement the solution you're envisioning for whatever underlying problem you're trying to solve.*

That said, if you want to know when elements are manually added or removed from your cache (e.g. via `.put()` or `.invalidate()`) wrap your cache in a [`ForwardingCache`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/ForwardingCache.html) implementation that invokes your function when these methods are called.

If you want to know when elements are automatically added (e.g. by `LoadingCache.get()` being called on a non-existent key) invoke your function from within the `load()` method you defined when you called [`CacheBuilder.build()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#build-com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader-).

If you want to know when elements are removed from your cache (either by eviction or manual removal) register your function as a [`RemovalListener`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#removalListener-com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener-).

You can of course also combine these strategies (e.g. use a `ForwardingCache` and a `RemovalListener`) in the same cache.